# Output of printf '\x41\n' | cat in Makefile is different than the output in shell

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, escaping

I am using GNU Make on Linux. Here is my Makefile.

```
foo:
    printf '\x41\n'

bar:
    printf '\x41\n' | cat
```

Here is the output:

```
$ make foo
printf '\x41\n'
A
$ make bar
printf '\x41\n' | cat
\x41
```

The shell being used is Dash:

```
# ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 12 04:41 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Why does the output become different when I pipe through `cat`?

Strangely, `dash` itself has a different behavior when I execute the commands directly on it.

```
$ printf '\x41\n'
\x41
$ printf '\x41\n' | cat
\x41
```

What is going on here? Why is the output of the commands in Makefile inconsistent with that in Dash?

Comment: `The same issue does not occur if I execute the commands directly on shell.` - but what shell? It looks like dash/something-that-/bin/sh-points-to vs Bash compatibility issue.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Added details about shell. It is dash.

Comment: There are three answers to your question explaining why the issue occur and how to avoid it. Why there is no one of them accepted to mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see different behavior is that the form `\xNN` is not defined in the POSIX standard for `printf`.  The standard only defines the behavior for special characters specified in octal, using `\oNNN`.  It doesn't support the hex form.

The reason for seeing different behavior is that in the simple case:

```
foo:
        printf '\x41\n'
```

`make` doesn't need to invoke a shell: it can run the command directly which invokes the `/usr/bin/printf` program on your system.  That program has extra features, in addition to what POSIX requires, and it can handle `\xNN` characters.

In the more complicated case:

```
bar:
        printf '\x41\n' | cat
```

This requires `make` to invoke the shell, because `make` can't handle pipelines etc.  When you invoke the shell it's using the shell's built-in `printf` not the separate program `/usr/bin/printf`.  Since your shell is `dash`, which only provides POSIX-conforming behaviors (for the most part), its `printf` built-in doesn't handle non-standard `\xNN` characters.

Short answer: stick with behaviors defined by POSIX and it will work all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In *foo* case an external printf executable is run instead of shell
builtin (see this answer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202302/variable-definition-in-bash-using-the-local-keyword/202326#202326
that explains the difference between shell builtin and external
executables) as you can see with strace::

```
$ strace -f make
(...)
[pid  1396] execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\x41\\n"], 0x56453618b880 /* 14 vars */ <unfinished ...>
```

so even though dash is used A is printed because printf which is a
part of coreutils understands \x sequence:

```
$ dash
$ /usr/bin/printf '\x41\n'
A
```

In *bar* case make runs dash builtin as you can see with strace:

```
$ strace -f make bar
(...)
[pid  1414] execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "printf '\\x41\\n' | cat"], 0x55835836a8e0 /* 14 vars */ <unfinished ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's summarize the outcome of the other answers using one line of statements where the output provides all of the evidence necessary to see that:

- Sticking to octal representation of characters does not have the problem of getting different results with and without piped `cat`
- `make` does run the system `printf` in the case of not piped `printf` and the shell with `printf` piped to `cat` what is the core reason why you see different behavior next to the fact that  the POSIX standard for `printf` defines only the behavior for special characters specified in octal notation using `\NNN` (but doesn't support `\xNN`)

With help of the provided command line anyone can now try to reproduce the problem on the own system with the side-effect of seeing which shell is used by make:

> $ cat Makefile; echo -----------; strace -o strace.out -f make; echo -----------; cat strace.out | grep 'printf' | grep -v 'ENOENT'

(don't forget to store the first part of the output in a file called `"Makefile"` before):

```
$ cat Makefile; echo -----------; strace -o strace.out -f make; echo -----------; cat strace.out | grep 'printf' | grep -v 'ENOENT'
all: pXA pXAcat poA poAcat
pXA:
    printf '\x41\n'
pXAcat:
    printf '\x41\n' | cat
poA:
    printf '\101\n'
poAcat:
    printf '\101\n' | cat
-----------
printf '\x41\n'
A
printf '\x41\n' | cat
\x41
printf '\101\n'
A
printf '\101\n' | cat
A
-----------
28434 write(1, "printf '\\x41\\n'\n", 16) = 16
28435 execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\x41\\n"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
28434 write(1, "printf '\\x41\\n' | cat\n", 22) = 22
28436 execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "printf '\\x41\\n' | cat"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
28434 write(1, "printf '\\101\\n'\n", 16) = 16
28439 execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\101\\n"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
28434 write(1, "printf '\\101\\n' | cat\n", 22) = 22
28440 execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "printf '\\101\\n' | cat"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
```

By the way: if you take a look at the first line of the `"strace.out"` file you can see which make is processing the Makefile:

```
28434 execve("/usr/bin/make", ["make"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
```

Below the code of the `"Makefile"` to save before running the long command line:

```
all: pXA pXAcat poA poAcat
pXA:
    printf '\x41\n'
pXAcat:
    printf '\x41\n' | cat
poA:
    printf '\101\n'
poAcat:
    printf '\101\n' | cat
```

And if your `make` does not give the same result as above adjust it to `make all` in order to get all of the output.

P.S. Notice that the indentation of the lines with `printf` in the `"Makefile"` must be done using TABs and not spaces (so replace spaces by tabs or copy the script from the editing and not viewing textbox).

P.S. P.S. As you can see in the output of `strace` the shell invoked by running `make` on my system is `sh` where the standard shell of systems `Terminal` is the `bash`. So 'same' commands run with `make` can differ in behavior compared to running them in the Terminal. As this can easily lead to confusion it is generally a good idea while using the command line to run a command or an executable to be fully aware that the result may differ from the result obtained for as the same command or executable assumed one if it is run in another context because of existence of multiple shells or different commands with same name. And it is also a good idea to be fully aware of the fact that running exactly the same program from within a given shell is not exactly the same thing if run within another shell or without a connection to a shell.